# How to replace words such as "is" in a string, without affecting "Pakistani" | nodejs

Tags: javascript, string, replace

How to replace words in Nodejs, such that if I want to replace a word `is` from below string to `done`:

```
He is a Pakistani and is a good person
```

the output only gives:

`He done a pakdonetani and done a good person` instead of `He done a Pakistani and done a good person`.
I am using this code:

```
var str = "He is a Pakistani and is a good person";
var res = str.replace(/is/g, "done");
console.log(res);
```

One can say that, do instead:

```
var res = str.replace(/ is /g, "done");
```

but it will fail for this string:

```
var str = "He is a Pakistani and a good person he is.";
```

To counter this case we can:

```
var res = str.replace(/ is/g, "done");
```

but it will fail for

```
var str = "He is a Pakistani, and furthur added 'is a good boy'"
```

If we do:

```
var res = str.replace(/ is/g, "done");
var res = res.replace(/is /g,"done ");
```

then it fails for this case:

```
var str = "He is a Pakistani, and furthur added 'is a good boy and a caring boy he is'. Besides he said that he lives on an island";
```

because it gives an output:

```
Hedone a Pakistani, and furthur added 'done a good boy and a caring boy hedone'. Besides he said that he lives on andoneland
```

Comment: Your first piece of code gives right output for the string `He is a Pakistani and is a good person`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use word boundaries, and search for the pattern `\bis\b`:

```js
var str = "He is a Pakistani, and furthur added 'is a good boy'"
var res = str.replace(/\bis\b/g, "done");
console.log(res);
```

Comment: New learning: `whole word only` replace.. :)